# Should we modify/edit a popular question to be more useful to others?

Tags: discussion

[One of my questions](https://askubuntu.com/questions/124292/what-is-the-correct-way-to-install-ati-catalyst-video-drivers/126513#126513) reached over 10,000 views at the weekend and when I was reviewing it I realized that reputation (up votes) doesn't reflect its popularity.  It made me think, while  the question title was attracting viewers, however the content may not be as useful as it could be.

My question here in meta is, should we tidy this question and make it more beneficial, for example the comments are not longer relevant and the question itself has the capacity to be edited and improved.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Yes! Totally! Absolutely! :)

Stack Exchange (and by extension, Ask Ubuntu) exists to make the internet a better place, and making a popular question useful to a wider audience (within reason) *totally* fits into that. Edit away, and for comments just toss up a flag for the mods to handle it.

Comment: Thanks, My thinking about asking this question is that I didn't want to change something that so many have read.  However, when you analyse the proportion of upvotes, I also wondered if the question title was just good bait but the content was dissapointing.  I will make the necessary changes and suggestions